# Evil DICOM -destination array was not long enough check destindex and length and the array's lower bounds

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dicom, evil-dicom

I am using EVIL DICOM image reader, it works well with some files, but some files give me this error:
destination array was not long enough check destindex and length and the array's lower bounds
I can't find the original website where I have purchased the program.
Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The error message is a general .NET message. Please provide more detailed information of where the error is occurring and if possible a stack trace. The "classic" Evil DICOM library can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/evildicom/). There is also a substantially re-worked new library available [here](https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM).

Comment: Thank you Anders, the error is in this line:        im = new ImageMatrix(openFileDialog.FileNames, progressBar1, progressLabel);Line 22 in the EvilDicomImageReader program, Form1.cs.  I did download the new DLL.  Any idea how I contact the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the Evil DICOM code (version 0.5.7), I assume that you are using the `ImageMatrix` constructor in a way that was not entirely planned for.

The constructor you are referring to takes an array of DICOM image files, where the size of each image is supposed to be the same for all images.

Upon construction, the `Image` array property is dimensioned to equal the size of one image times the length of the DICOM image array in the private method `IntializeMatrix`.

Next, the constructor loops over all image files and inserts the pixel data from each file into the `Image` property in the `AppendImageToMatrix` method. The start position of the copied pixel data in the `Image` is determined by the DICOM file `ImageNumber`.

If the `ImageNumber` is too high in relation to the size of the `Image` array, pixel data is copied to position 0 in the `Image` array.

**However!** If the start position is *equal* to the length of the `Image` array, which will happen if the `ImageNumber` is exactly one more than the number of files, the start position will not be modified and there will be an attempt to write to a non-existing position in the `Image` array!

The line where this is happening is the fourth line in `AppendImageToMatrix`, which reads:

```
if (offset > Image.Length) { offset = 0; }
```

If you are building the library yourself, you might want to change the `>` operator to a `>=` operator, then the application will at least not throw. Alternatively, you could consider a more fail-safe handling altogether of the pixel data copying. There is not room to elaborate on that here, though :-)

I cannot right away find the `ImageMatrix` class in the [updated version of Evil DICOM](https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM). However, if you run into problems with the old or the new code, consider reporting these problems on the [Issues tab](https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM/issues) of the Evil DICOM Github repository.

**UPDATE** Note that the `ImageNumber` property is equal to the DICOM attribute *Instance Number*, tag (0020,0013).

Comment: Thank you Anders, I will have to wait until Monday for one of my experience programmers; meanwhile I would like to know if Evil DICOM can read CAD Images (Animated DICOM).

Comment: I am pretty sure Evil DICOM is _not_ capable of handling animated DICOM images, but I do not know for certain.

Comment: To follow up: I have now also reproduced the exact same error by following the above description. By changing to `>=` the exception went away. So, the above answer was not just guess-work :-)

Comment: Thanks again for you support.  I did change offset > to offest >= in class ImageMatrix.  Changed the reference in ImageReader to then new DLL, I got the same error!  I am using EVILDICOM 3.5 library.  Thanks

Comment: This sounds very strange? Are you sure you have rebuilt correctly and referenced the newly built DLL? The version number you are referring to is unknown to me, the version numbers at Sourceforge are 0.05.7 or less? Also, the latest code on [Github](https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM) does not even contain `ImageMatrix`, so I am unsure what code you are actually working with?

Comment: Thank you again for your support, you are right; I rebuilt the program using the new DLL (downloaded) it it worked well, however for CAD CT image it did not.  The Library 3.5 is the .Net that I have purchased in Febraury, the DLL was version 4.  Thanks again Anders.